# How to return a value from one python script to another?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, cross-reference

file1.py

```
from processing file import sendfunction


class ban(): 
    def returnhello(): 
        x = "hello"
        return x #gives reply a value of "hello replied" in processingfile

print(sendfunction.reply()) #this should fetch the value of reply from processingfile,right?
```

processingfile.py

```
from file1 import ban
class sendfunction():
    def reply():
        reply = (ban.returnhello() + " replied")
        return reply
```

I can't really seem to get any results, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `processing file` shouldn't have spaces while importing.

Comment: oh sorry about that, will make that amendment, thank you @RahulChawla

Answer (score 3):

You need to create `object` of class `ban` before calling his `member function` as follows

```
from file1 import ban
class sendfunction():
    def reply(self):   # Member methods must have `self` as first argument
        b = ban()      # <------- here creation of object
        reply = (b.returnhello() + " replied")
        return reply
```

OR, you make `returnhello` method as `static` method. Then you don't need to create an `object` of class beforehand to use.

```
class ban(): 
    @staticmethod       # <---- this is how you make static method
    def returnhello():  # Static methods don't require `self` as first arugment
        x = "hello"
        return x #gives reply a value of "hello replied" in processingfile
```

`BTW:` Good programming practice is that, you always start you class name with `Capital` Letter.
And function and variable names should be lowercase with underscores, so `returnhello()` should be `return_hello()`. As mentioned [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names).

Answer (score 0):

Lets suppose we have two file A.py and B.py

A.py

```
a = 3
print('saying hi in A')
```

B.py

```
from A import a
print('The value of a is %s in B' % str(a))
```

On executing B.py you get the following output:

```
└> python B.py
saying hi in A
The value of a is 3 in B
```